# How do I return an empty new list?

Tags: python

I'm pretty new to Python and I'm trying to remember the syntax for returning an empty new list. Here is my code for context:

```
      if self.LinkedList == 0:
        if in_place==True:
          return None 
        else: 
          return new_list[0]
```

Basically what's happening is if the LinkedList is empty and in place it will do nothing, else if it's empty and no "in_place" I want it to return an empty new list.

There's going to be more to this code as it's a part of a function reverse.. def reverse(self, in_place==False) so the in_place is False by default.

The "return new_list[0]" was my sad attempt after researching myself first. I have an abstract idea but i'm not 100% sure.

I appreciate anyone's time and patience with this question. Thank you!

Comment: An empty list is bracket only `[]` https://www.google.com/search?q=python+empty+list is google so hard to use ? 100 times faster than writing a post here

Comment: What kind of "list" are you talking about?

Comment: What is `new_list`? Is this a defined variable? You probably just want `return []` based on your description

Comment: Thank you G. Anderson. I wasn't sure if I needed to actually name this new list or not.

Comment: You might check out the python documentation, https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing.